# A physical understanding of the 2/3 in the Sachs-Wolfe effect

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

I am trying to develop an intuitive but quantitative understanding of the factor of 2/3 in the Sachs-Wolfe effect. I believe I have a picture that makes sense but it relies on one assumption I don't know how to justify.

*Question*

The situation is that we have an observer in a part of space with perturbed gravitational potential $\delta\phi$. This observer is wearing a watch that starts at $t=0$ at the Big Bang. What time does the watch read at the moment of recombination? If the observer is in an "average background" part of space with $\delta\phi=0$ then the watch reads $t=400,000\, \rm years$. Is this time independent of $\delta\phi$? In other words, do perturbations change how long it takes before recombination?

...and just for completeness, the rest of SW argument:

If that locally measured time of recombination (call it $t_L$) is independent of $\delta\phi$ then we can argue that a far away observer will see recombination happening in that perturbed region at a time $t_L \delta\phi$ earlier than if $\delta\phi$ in that region had been $0$. This is just because of gravitational time dilation: when the perturbed observer's watch reads $t_L$ the far away observer's watch reads $t_L(1-\delta\phi)$. (This relies on $\delta\phi$ being independent of time, as it is during matter domination.)

This earlier time means that the photons have had more time to redshift on their way to Earth: their temperature today T is proportional to the scale factor $a$ when they were emitted ($T = 3000 {\rm K}\, a\,/ \,a_{\rm today}$). So the fractional change in their temperature at Earth (relative to the average CMB temperature) is

$$\frac{\delta T}{T} = \frac{\delta a}{a} = \frac{\dot{a} \delta t}{a} = -\frac{\dot{a}}{a}t_L\delta\phi = -\frac{2}{3}\delta\phi,$$

for $a \propto t^{2/3}$ in the matter-dominated era.

There is one other source of temperature shift: when photons leave the perturbed area (with potential $\delta \phi$) they get gravitationally blue-shifted and thir energy changes by $E\delta\phi$ (i.e. if $\delta\phi<0$ they have to "climb out" and lose energy in the process, and vice versa if they are "rolling downhill" when $\delta\phi>0$). This shifts the temperature by a fractional amount $\frac{\delta T}{T} = \delta\phi$. The net result is that the fractional temperature change for the [Sachs-Wolfe effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect) is the sum of the two effects:

$$\left( \frac{\delta T}{T} \right)_{\rm SW} = \frac{1}{3}\delta\phi.$$

(This is all based on trying to make sense of section 2.6 of Weinberg's Cosmology book.)

Comment: This looks right to me, and it is a lot clearer than all the presentations I have read (they are all much too hand-waving). So: thanks!